# Mysql Query for two tables with null values

Tags: mysql

Have two tables one is customer and other prize amount

```
**Customer**          **PrizeAmount**
*CustomerId Amount*      *CustomerId PrizeAmt*   
1  500                   1          2000
                         1          2000
```

Resultant query should be like this

```
CustomerId Amount PrizeAmt
1          500     2000
1          (NULL)  2000
```

So how to write query for above result

Comment: Hint: `JOIN` ...

Comment: What have you tried and why the null

Comment: I tried using "JOIN" and null because in customer table have single entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;

CREATE TABLE T (CID INT , AMOUNT_INVESTED INT);
CREATE TABLE T1 (CID INT, AMOUNT_WON INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,500);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1,2000),(1,2000);

SELECT CID,AMOUNT_INVESTED,AMOUNT_WON
FROM
(
SELECT T.CID,IF(T.CID <> @P, T.AMOUNT_INVESTED,NULL) AMOUNT_INVESTED, T1.AMOUNT_WON,
         @P:=T.CID
FROM T
JOIN T1 ON T.CID = T1.CID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @P:=0) P
) S

+------+-----------------+------------+
| CID  | AMOUNT_INVESTED | AMOUNT_WON |
+------+-----------------+------------+
|    1 |             500 |       2000 |
|    1 |            NULL |       2000 |
+------+-----------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

With left join you can do it

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

so

```
select customer_id as custo_id,amount,prize_amt 
from customer 
left join prize_amount on customer.customer_id=prize_amount.customer_id
```

[Left Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: even if used left join not getting result as expected

Comment: Actual Result Required like this->Customer_Id | Amount | PrizeAmt

Comment: 1| 500 |2000, 1|(NULL)|2000